# Sqlite3 and PDO issue with ORDER BY

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, sql-order-by

I try to use the SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column
```

via an PDO-Object in PHP. Problem is, that I always get an error (Call to a member function fetchall() on a non-object - that means, the query did not return a PDO-object) when using the names of all columnname EXCEPT for ID. When I query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID
```

it works. ID is the PRIMARY INTEGER KEY, all other columns are TEXT or NUMERIC, neither of them would works with the ORDER BY clause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *could* be an issue with temporary files as you've suggested in your comment to Frank Heikens's answer.

http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html says:

> 2.6 Transient Indices
>
> SQLite may make use of transient indices to implement SQL language features such as:
>
>     * An ORDER BY or GROUP BY clause
>     * The DISTINCT keyword in an aggregate query
>     * Compound SELECT statements joined by UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT
>
> Each transient index is stored in its own temporary file.

If and where files are created is controlled by `SQLITE_TEMP_STORE`, `PRAGMA temp_store` and `PRAGMA temp_store_directory` , see http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

Comment: Yes, thanks it was the SQLITE_TEMP_STORE variable. I have to change it before using ORDER BY because otherwise sqlite tries to write a temporary file. Also see this: http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#tempstore

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `ORDER BY` statement with
`ORDER BY CAST(COLUMN AS REAL)`.
It can sort `REAL` values.